# Mysql function to update foreign key

Tags: mysql, function, duplicates

I have a table **A** with duplicate data and I would like to normalize it. But there is another table **B** which refers to table **A** ids. There is no real foreign key. It is only the fact. I would like to create temp. table **C** and fill it by use **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** to remove duplicities from table **A**. But so I lose some ids which make references to from table **B** to table **A**.

I would like to write a function which will be called like

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = setNewId(`id`, VALUES(`id`))
```

Is it possible to make function **setNewId()** which will update table **C.id** and **B.id** to new value on dulicate key update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create `C` with all the duplicate values of `unique_field` removed.

```
CREATE TABLE C LIKE A;
ALTER TABLE C ADD UNIQUE INDEX (unique_field);
INSERT IGNORE INTO C
SELECT * FROM A;
```

After you create `C`, you can use a join between `A` and `C` to find the corresponding ID, and use that to update `B`.

```
UPDATE B
JOIN A ON B.foreign_key = A.id
JOIN C ON C.unique_field = A.unique_field AND C.id != A.id
SET B.foreign_key = C.id;
```

After that's done, drop `A` and rename `C` to `A`.

Comment: He doesn't even have a C yet, Barmar

Comment: He said he's going to create C, I think he knows how to do that.

Comment: Well, I added it to the answer anyway.

Comment: yea, one of my favorite calls, `insert ignore`. Long live that call :p ... Some talk of it getting ditched, in 5.7. Not sure.

Comment: I am still with you. Not enough time to try it. Thanks for now.